# Visual Studio 2015 still didn't fix the error when setting IsChecked to {x:Null}?

Tags: wpf, xaml

A simple project with only a window and a check box like this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Null}"/>
```

Will throw this error:

```
Invalid value for property 'IsChecked':  
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.XmlValue'
```

This problem was said to be fixed 4 months ago [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1112682/wpf-checkbox-ischecked-cannot-be-set-to-indeterminate)

But still presets in the enterprise final version! 
proof : 
[image]
[image]

Is there any fix / workaround for this annoying problem?
Edit : I added a new ticket to microsoft about this [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1611888/xaml-editor-error-invalid-value-for-property-in-handler-and-ischecked-bug-remains-in-the-enterprise-version-of-vs-2015)

Comment: Who cares? just don't use the XAML designer.

Comment: You should post your feedback there to let them know.

Comment: @bigworld12 And what's your question?

Comment: i do care as intellisense gets like a 5 ~ 7 seconds delay with like 18 errors of this kind

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko my question is : is there a fix / workaround for this annoying problem ?

Comment: Solution: disable the XAML designer. No one uses that.

Comment: @Bolu i sent like 5 feedbacks until now but all they get are stupid responses

Comment: @HighCore it's in the XAML debugger it self not the designer

Comment: Not sure what might be different on my machine/Installation. But the  community version does not show any error. Blend is happy about the statement as well.

Comment: i had community version before the enterprise one , it had the same error

Comment: i posted a new ticket on microsoft https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1611888/xaml-editor-error-invalid-value-for-property-in-handler-and-ischecked-bug-remains-in-the-enterprise-version-of-vs-2015

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in a vb.net wpf project only , and a c# wpf project didn't have this problem , so it's a VB specific bug